# jQuery .each() not logging msg onto Console

Tags: jquery

I'm stumped on a very simple implementation of jQuery's each method. I copied the code below from https://api.jquery.com/each/ to get an understanding of how the each method works. After unsuccessfully testing the html/js code locally, I copied it to JSBin, and lo and behold it worked. Can someone point out where I went wrong? I suspect it's the jQuery CDN I've linked to...

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="ex.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

js

```
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

Comment: The script element needs to be after the elements it tries to access, and/or you could wrap the JS shown in a document ready handler. (JSBin may do this automatically - certainly JSFiddle uses an onload handler by default.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to use the ready function is this:

```
$(function() {
     $( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
         console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
     });
});
```

This is also the first syntax mentioned in the api. You might notice, that there is no "ready" in the code at all. That is because the handler will be initialized after the DOM has been loaded.

> jQuery offers several ways to attach a function that will run when the DOM is ready. All of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> - $( handler )
> - $( document ).ready( handler )
> - $( "document" ).ready( handler )
> - $( "img" ).ready( handler )
> - $().ready( handler )
>
> As of jQuery 3.0, only the first syntax is recommended; the other syntaxes still work but are deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

You should load your JS script in [jQuery's on ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) method like this:

```
$(function() {
   $( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
      console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
   });
});
```

> The `.ready()` method offers a way to run JavaScript code as soon as the
>   page's Document Object Model (DOM) becomes safe to manipulate. This
>   will often be a good time to perform tasks that are needed before the
>   user views or interacts with the page, for example to add event
>   handlers and initialize plugins. When multiple functions are added via
>   successive calls to this method, they run when the DOM is ready in the
>   order in which they are added. As of jQuery 3.0, jQuery ensures that
>   an exception occuring in one handler does not prevent subsequently
>   added handlers from executing.

Hope this helps!